# What's the proper sentence to use when asking someone whether they know something, using the sentence structure "I was wondering ____?"?

Tags: sentence-choice

Let's say that, as an office worker, you're looking for someone in a different department that could help you with a project X. You go up to one of your colleagues and want to ask him whether he knows someone who could help you with this project (using the sentence structure "I was wondering __?" in your question).

Which of the following sentences is the correct one to use? (I'd appreciate it if you'd let me know about any better sentences)

> I was wondering whether you know someone who can help me with this project?
>
> I was wondering if you know someone who can help me with this project?
>
> I was wondering who I can speak to to get help with project X from?

This final sentence doesn't sound right to me; but I'm not sure how I can improve it.

Comment: Stylistically speaking, those can either be questions or statements. While some people will raise their voice at the end, and ask them in the form of a question, others will simply state them as facts, without the rising intonation or question mark in writing. I personally never phrase questions that way (but I know other people do). I would use *Do you know someone . . .?* and *Can I speak to someone . . .?*

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are all correct grammatically, so it's just a matter of which you feel most comfortable with.

The final sentence does sound a little odd, I'd consider dropping the from off the end:

> I was wondering who I can **/could** speak to to get help with project X?

Whether and if are synonymous in this context. Although "whether" could possibly be considered more grammatically correct since there is an implied alternative:

> I was wondering weather [or not] you know someone who can help...

[Source](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/if-versus-whether)